# DART Conditional find and replace using Regex

Tags: regex, dart

I have a string that sometimes contains a certain substring at the end and sometimes does not. When the string is present I want to update its value. When it is absent I want to add it at the end of the existing string.

For example:

```
int _newCount = 7;
_myString = 'The count is: COUNT=1;'
_myString2 = 'The count is: '
_rRuleString.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('COUNT=(.*?)\;'), (match) {

//if there is a match (like in _myString) update the count to value of _newCount
//if there is no match (like in _myString2) add COUNT=1; to the string

}
```

I have tried using a return of:

```
return "${match.group(1).isEmpty ? _myString + ;COUNT=1;' : 'COUNT=$_newCount;'}";
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Since string #2 has no match, no replacement can be done. Do you want to match `COUNT=<digits>` after `count is:`? Is `count is:` string always present?

Comment: count is: is not a reliable match as it may change. 
If no match is found for 'COUNT=<digits>;  I want to add it to the string.

Comment: Where? At the end?

Comment: Yes- I want to append it to the end of the string.

Comment: One more: do you expect `COUNT=<digits>;` *always at the end of string*?

Comment: Yes. COUNT=<digits>; (if present) will always be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `replaceAllMatched` will only perform a replacement if there is a match, else, there will be no replacement (insertion is still a replacement of an empty string with some string).

Your expected matches are always at the end of the string, and you may leverage this in your current code. You need a regex that *optionally* matches `COUNT=` and then some text up to the first `;` including the char and then checks if the current position is the end of string.

Then, just follow the logic: if Group 1 is matched, set the new count value, else, add the `COUNT=1;` string:

The regex is

```
(COUNT=[^;]*;)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/raHKsK/2/).

**Details**

- `(COUNT=[^;]*;)?` - an optional group 1: `COUNT=`, any 0 or more chars other than `;` and then a `;`
- `$` - end of string.

Dart code:

```
_myString.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp(r'(COUNT=[^;]*;)?$'), (match) {
     return match.group(0).isEmpty ? "COUNT=1;" : "COUNT=$_newCount;" ; }
)
```

Note the use of `replaceFirstMatched`, you need to replace *only* the first match.